# how to add remove and add button with lines using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

i want to add remove and add buttons with the fields on row hover like [this](https://edgelogics.freshbooks.com/menu.php?route=createInvoice).

but my dynamic fields generate on `button click`
which changes i can do for above link design?
here is my code:

```
<tr>         
     <td colspan=7 width=800><div id="input1" style="margin-bottom:4px;" class="clonedInput"><select class="items" name="items" style="width:127px; float:left;" id="items"><option value="1" selected="selected" disabled="disabled"></option></select>
     <textarea name="description" id="description" class="description" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:209px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;"></textarea>
     <input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" class="unitprice" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px -1px 0;">
     <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="quantity" style="float:left; display: block; height: 30px; width:64px; border-radius:0px; margin: -1px 1px 0;">
     <select name="firsttax" id="firsttax" style=" float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:106px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px -1px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected" ></option></select>
     <select name="secondtax" id="secondtax" style="float:left; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; margin: -2px 0px 0;"><option value="1" selected="selected"></option></select>
     <input type="text" name="linetotal" id="linetotal" class="linetotal" placeholder="0.00" readonly style="float:right; display: block; height: 31px; width:107px; border-radius:0px; background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align:right; margin: -31px -1px 0;">


     </div>
     </td></tr>
```

and here is my `javascript` code to generate dynamically fields:

```
 $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');

       $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length;
        var newNum = num + 1;

        var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);
        newElem.find(':input').each(function () {
            $('form select[name=items]').attr('name', 'items'+newNum);
            $('form select[id=items]').attr('id', 'items'+newNum);

            $('form textarea[name=description]').attr('name', 'description'+newNum);
            $('form textarea[id=description]').attr('id', 'description'+newNum);

            $('form input[name=unitprice]').attr('name', 'unitprice'+newNum);
            $('form input[id=unitprice]').attr('id', 'unitprice'+newNum);

            $('form input[name=quantity]').attr('name', 'quantity'+newNum);
            $('form input[id=quantity]').attr('id', 'quantity'+newNum);

            $('form select[name=firsttax]').attr('name', 'firsttax'+newNum);
            $('form select[id=firsttax]').attr('id', 'firsttax'+newNum);

            $('form select[name=secondtax]').attr('name', 'secondtax'+newNum);
            $('form select[id=secondtax]').attr('id', 'secondtax'+newNum);

            $('form input[name=linetotal]').attr('name', 'linetotal'+newNum);
            $('form input[id=linetotal]').attr('id', 'linetotal'+newNum);
            $('#itemscounter').val(+newNum);
        });

        $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

        //if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

        $('#btnDel').click(function() {
            var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

            $('#input' + num).remove();
            $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled',false);
            if (num-1 === 1)
                $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
        });

        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

and here is my buttons:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAdd" value="Add Row" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDel" value="Remove Row" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```js
jQuery(document).on("ready", function() {

  initAddRows();

});

function initAddRows() {

  var template = jQuery("#template"),
      dataRows = jQuery("#dataRows");

  jQuery("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {

    var newRow = template.clone(true, true),
        fieldRows = dataRows.find(".fieldRow");

    newRow.attr('id', 'row' + (fieldRows.length + 1)).find('[id]').each(function() {

      jQuery(this).attr("id", jQuery(this).attr("id") + (fieldRows.length + 1));

    });

    fieldRows.filter(":last").after(newRow);

  });

  dataRows.on("click", ".remove", function() {

    jQuery(this).parent().remove();

  });
}
```

```css
 .fieldRow {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
 
 .fieldRow .field {
   float: left;
   margin: 0 10px 0 0;
 }
 
 .fieldRow select.field {
   padding: 1px;
 }
 
 .buttonHolder {
   border-top: solid 5px #ccc;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 
 #template .button.remove {
   display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dataRows">
  <div class="fieldRow" id="template">
    <select class="items field" name="items" id="items" disabled="disabled">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Value</option>
      <option value="1"></option>
      <option value="1"></option>
    </select>

    <textarea name="description" id="description" class="description field"></textarea>

    <input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" class="unitprice field">

    <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" class="quantity field">

    <select name="firsttax" id="firsttax" class="field">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Value</option>
    </select>
    <select name="secondtax" id="secondtax" class="field">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Value</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="linetotal" id="linetotal" class="linetotal field" placeholder="0.00" readonly>

    <input type="button" class="button remove" id="btnDel" value="Remove Row" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttonHolder">
  <input type="button" class="button add" id="btnAdd" value="Add Row" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, problem is cool. :)
Here is the solution.

**HTML Markup**

```
<div class="formContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="flt">
            <select name="items" id="items">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="flt"><textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea></div>
        <div class="flt"><input type="text" name="unitprice" id="unitprice" /></div>
        <div class="flt"><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" /></div>
        <div class="flt">
            <select name="firsttax" id="firsttax">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="flt">
            <select name="secondtax" id="secondtax">
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="flt"><input type="text" name="linetotal" id="linetotal" readonly /></div>
        <div class="flt"><input type="button" class="addRow" name="addRow" value="+" /></div>
        <div class="flt"><input type="button" class="removeRow" name="removeRow" value="-" /></div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fieldRow {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .fieldRow .field {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
    .fieldRow select.field {
        padding: 1px;
    }
    .buttonHolder {
        border-top: solid 5px #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #template .button.remove {
        display: none;  
    }
```

**And JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){
    var rowItem = $(".row");

    $(".formContainer").on("click", ".addRow", function(){
        var newItem = rowItem.clone(),
            rowIndex = $(".row").length;

        $(":input", newItem).each(function(c, obj){
            $(obj).attr("id", $(obj).attr("name") + rowIndex);
        });
        //$(this).parent().parent().after(newItem); // adds just after the current line
       $(".formContainer").append(newItem); // adds At the end of the container
    })
    .on("click", ".removeRow", function(){
        if($(".row").length > 1){
            $(this).parents(".row").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

You have two ways to add the row:

1. If want to add just after the current row
2. If want to add the row at the end of the form

Both are there in the JS above, (one is commented as of now)

Here is the working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/8pJ4P/1/

*If you like animations, you can check out this one:* http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/8pJ4P/4/